# Jquery ui Drag/Drop and Sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have two `div` containers

1. `top_div`
2. `bottom_div`

initially `top_div` will be blank. I'm using jQuery UI drag and drop. I'm able to drag contents from `bottom_div` to `top_div`.

My requirement is in above `top_div` I need to sort (using sortable jQuery UI) the contents.
And after sorting when I refresh the page it should not change its position.

Please any help is appreciated Thanks!

**Html Code**

```html
<div id="top_div">

</div>
<br/>
<div id="bottom_div">
    <ul>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Sachin Tendulkar</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Ab de Villiers</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">MS Dhoni</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Ricky Ponting</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Rahul</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Jquery Code**

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () 
    {
        $("#bottom_div li").draggable({
            tolerance:'fit',
            revert: "invalid",
            refreshPositions: true,
            drag: function (event, ui) 
            {
                ui.helper.addClass("draggable");
            },
            stop: function (event, ui) 
            {
                ui.helper.removeClass("draggable");
            }
        });
        $("#top_div").droppable(
        {
            drop: function (event, ui) 
            {
                if ($("#top_div li").length == 0) 
                {
                    $("#top_div").html("");
                }
                ui.draggable.addClass("dropped");
                $("#top_div").append(ui.draggable).sortable();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Sorting is possible but you can not have as it is once you refresh your page.

Comment: @divy3993 Thank you could u help me in doing sorting in my requirement.. Is thr any predefined event/method in jquery UI were it will retain its position after sorting Thanks!!

Comment: @peh Thank You so much!!